# Does the c++ specify a hash function for references?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, standard-library

My question is a quick one.

Does the C++ standard library implement a hash function for references, like `std::hash<T&>`

Comment: Barry is right; this raises more questions than it asks: What should hash of a reference do? Should it propagate the hash of the referenced value? Or should it hash the reference 'itself', i.e. the address where the object resides? Both might be desirable in different situations, e.g. hashing by address can be desirable to avoid using pointers, where the key is the specific instance, not just its apparent value (if it even *has* any value semantic). Maybe the Committee thought it was easy enough for users to code whichever semantics they want, in a few lines, than to standardise both varieties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not. The specializations enumerated in [function.objects] are:

> ```
> // Hash function specializations
> template <> struct hash<bool>;
> template <> struct hash<char>;
> template <> struct hash<signed char>;
> template <> struct hash<unsigned char>;
> template <> struct hash<char16_t>;
> template <> struct hash<char32_t>;
> template <> struct hash<wchar_t>;
> template <> struct hash<short>;
> template <> struct hash<unsigned short>;
> template <> struct hash<int>;
> template <> struct hash<unsigned int>;
> template <> struct hash<long>;
> template <> struct hash<long long>;
> template <> struct hash<unsigned long>;
> template <> struct hash<unsigned long long>;
>
> template <> struct hash<float>;
> template <> struct hash<double>;
> template <> struct hash<long double>;
>
> template<class T> struct hash<T*>;
> ```

Furthermore, what would such a thing even mean?

Comment: And btw, it would be UB to specialize it (as user) for `T&`.